# Update SQL Server 2016 from RTM to SP1

Tags: sql-server-2016, update

I have SQL Server 2016 RTM installed and would like to update it to SP1. When I run an SP1 cumulative update, it fails because there is nothing to update. Presumably this is because it needs SP1 to be installed first. When I run the SP1 installer, it wants to create a new instance.

How can I update an existing instance from RTM to SP1 without having to uninstall and reinstall the instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you've downloaded a copy of the full SQL Server 2016 (with SP1) installer. (Microsoft often distributes the installer with the latest service pack built in.)

Instead, [download Service Pack 1 by itself](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54276), then apply the latest cumulative update.

Comment: This resolved the issue. I had downloaded the full Express Edition SP1 installer from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: @GuruJosh Great, glad I could help.